# I want to create a multi-tabbed spreadsheet using coldfusion

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I am trying to create an Excel spreadsheet (having multiple worksheets and nested tables) by using ColdFusion 8. Although I came across quite a few solutions , I still can't find anything for my specific requirements, which is to make the spreadsheet contain multiple worksheets and each worksheet will contain nested tables.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Might want to try looking into Aspose.Cells for Java although that comes at a cost for the software and perhaps it could be done with POI or some other method.  The Aspose route is pretty simple to do via using it and ColdFusion.  On their forums I have recently worked out with them on how to load their libraries as well as how to write data into sheets.  Probably could use those postings along with their docs to figure out how to make sheets and get your data in them.

Comment: As you say there are quite a few solutions out there ;) So which ones did you find - and more specifically -  *how* did they not meet your requirements?

Comment: Leigh,  I have seen poi by Ben nadel,  I can't explore cfspreadsheet tag coz this is coldfusion8, I can not use nested cftable tag either because that doesn't work. So, I'm stuck in a corner.. :P

Answer (score 1):

Check out the POI blog posts put together by Ben Nadel. http://www.bennadel.com/projects/poi-utility.htm I use this and it works great. Very easy to get set up

Comment: POI works for multiple worksheets but its hard to make a nested table,  (like a table inside a cell ) ... so if you could let me know if nested tables are possible in POI